# Algorithm for finding power

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, exponentiation

I has been searching for a high precision library in PHP to do calculations like $$232323232323^{121212.2232323232}$$ etc (ie, with very large numbers, including decimals), but failed to get any. Hence I decided to write my own.

Could you suggest the possible approaches to do calculations like $$232323232323^{121212.2232323232}?$$

One possible approach could be 
$$232323232323^{121212.2232323232}
= 232323232323^{121212} * 232323232323^{0.2232323232}$$

Doing this using log and exp might be another option but then exp and log function logic is a problem

Using Taylor series migh be another option, but it is a lengthy process.

Experts, please advise

Comment: Remember you only have a maximum precision. Maybe computer algebra systems (like Mathematica) which actually can compute those analytical and not numerical is what you search for

Comment: $232323232323^{121212.2232323232}$ has over $10^{6}$ digits. Are you sure you want to compute this?

Comment: yes, I am developing an app for this to do huge calculations.